# How to overlay Long/Lat points on a existing map

Tags: tableau-api

I have an existing map of ward in Chicago in Tableau:
[image: Chicago by ward]

I have a separate CSV file, linked to primary data source by Ward.  It contains pairings of Long/Lat points.  I can make a map of it by itself, but cannot find a way to place the points on this map.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to overlay the dots to the existing area map you will need to use dual axis. Steps to follow are:

1. drag latitude (or longitude) from the csv datasource to rows (or columns); this will create another map
2. right click on the newly added measure and select "Dual axis"; this will overlap the two maps
3. in the marks box on the left you will be able to select different display settings for the two axis you will then have

You can also find a nice tutorial [here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/maps_dualaxis.htm)